# A peculiar transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra

True/False: If $T : V\rightarrow W$ for real vector spaces $V$ and $W$, and satisfies $T(0) = 0$ and $T(−v) = −T(v)$ for all $v \in V$, then $T$ is a linear transformation.

Comment: Welcome! As it is customary on this site, you may want to explain what your guess is about the question you asked and why. Show how far you have been able to each on your own. You may now edit your question. Also, the title should be more descriptive, even if it is significantly longer.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is false: consider $V = W = \mathbb{R}$. Then the conditions you have imposed imply $T$ is odd and there are plenty of nonlinear odd functions.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For any two vector spaces $V$ and $W$, there is a counterexample:  Let $v_0$ and $w_0$ be nonzero vectors in $V$ and $W$, respectively, and define $T:V\to W$ by $T(v_0)=w_0$, $T(-v_0)=-w_0$, and $T(v)=0$ for all $v\not=\pm v_o$.

Comment: But why it is NOT linear?

Comment: @AriBelenkiy, because $T(2v_0)=0\not=2T(v_0)$.